# Draw points on scatterplot

Tags: java, user-interface, points

I'm reading 2 values from my raspberry pi into java code.
These values are X and Y Coordinates.
I would like to see these coordinates on a plot in java.
I've written code to design a plot with a coordinate.
My question is how to make this coordinate dynamic, so it changes position.

This is what I've got so far:

```
public class Scatter2 extends Application {
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("Scatter Chart Sample");
    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(-10, 10, 1);
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(-10, 10, 1);        
    final ScatterChart<Number,Number> sc = new
        ScatterChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
    xAxis.setLabel("X");                
    yAxis.setLabel("Y");
    sc.setTitle("Locatie");


    XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
    series1.setName("Equities");
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 7.2));


    sc.getData().addAll(series1);
    Scene scene  = new Scene(sc, 500, 400);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();  
}
```

So the point in the example (1,7.2) should change to 2 variables that can change..

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: there is a way you can plot the movement in java using xyseriescollection may be you may find answer there Better spare some time to take a look.